# What do you call an appeal to a higher power?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a general word for it, but I don't mind if you can only think of a word used in a legal context, such as when we try to appeal to a higher legal authority, or a word used with a religious connotation, such as when we try to appeal to a higher power, such as a God.

Comment: In a legal sense, *appeal* ***is*** the word you're looking for. (In that context, it [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appeal) "*law* : a legal proceeding by which a case is brought before a higher court for review of the decision of a lower court."

Comment: In the religious sense, an appeal to a higher power is a **prayer**.

Comment: Does such a word exist in any other language that you know?  Have you used a bilingual dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a legal sense, *appeal* is the word you're looking for. (In that context, it means "a legal proceeding by which a case is brought before a higher court for review of the decision of a lower court."

In the religious sense, an appeal to a higher power is a *prayer*.